# Tkinter AssertionError: Python3 Web App using selenium won't input search term in driver.title

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I have been learning python for the past 10 months; I am also new to StackOverflow so hope you will forgive any errors in communicating here. My simple web application uses Selenium to automatically go to a specific website and enters a search term in the driver.title input box. Now all works but I get an AssertionError. I looked on StackOverflow and other websites but couldn't figure out how to solve this one. My goal was to teach myself how to use Selenium to automate. My app was built using Jupyter Notebook v6.0.1 which uses Python3.7.

I would be grateful for your help/tips. Many Thanks, Sean

Here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/seankerr/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-9-c3e0a628cdec>", line 38, in hackathons
    assert "hackathons" in driver.title
AssertionError
```

Here is the python code:

```
import selenium
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox  #SEAN NOTE: you don't need to import message box from
#tkinter separately because you have already imported '*' all tkinter tools/widgets
import os
import subprocess
import platform
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def ask_quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit","Are you sure you want to quit the application and close the window?"):
        root.destroy()
        
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Hackathon Fetcher")
root.geometry('200x200+200+200')
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ask_quit)


def raise_app(root: Tk):
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.title("Test Title")
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        tmpl = 'tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of every process whose unix id is {} to true'
        script = tmpl.format(os.getpid())
        output = subprocess.check_call(['/usr/bin/osascript', '-e', script])
    root.after(0, lambda: root.attributes("-topmost", False))
    
def hackathons():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
    driver.get("https://challengerocket.com/hackathons-and-challenges.html")
    assert "hackathons" in driver.title    
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("searchitems")
    elem.send_keys("python")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
Button(root, text= 'Fetch Python Hackathons', command = hackathons).pack(padx = 20)
#Button(root, text= "Quit", command = ask_quit).pack(expand=1, fill=tk.Y)   
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What  have you done to debug this? Have you examined `driver.title` to make sure it is what you're assuming it is?

Comment: Hi Bryan - thanks for responding: the driver.title selenium locator worked just fine last week, i.e., the code inserted the search term and the output was what I expected. Recently I installed Python 3.9 but that shouldn't affect Anaconda in that it uses 3.7 - also, I uninstalled 3.8 (it is used in other virtual environments) and 3.9, then reinstalled them. Shouldn't affect this program though. I haven't 'debugged' as I am still learning. Can you recommend an approach please? Otherwise, can't figure it out. Cheers

Comment: I didn't ask if it _should_ work, you need to verify that it _is_ working. It almost certainly is not returning what you think it's returning, and knowing what it _is_ returning will help you solve the problem. Just add a `print` statement before the assert to see what it actually is: `print(f"title: '{driver.title}'")`

Comment: Bryan: that was spot on! I can see that my assertion term "hackathons" is in fact not in the website title element: title: 'Coding & hiring challenges: Java, PHP, JavaScript, Cybersecurity and more | ChallengeRocket.com' - Also, given the wrong assertion, the send_keys() would not input 'python' into the input box named "searchitem". I am grateful to you for prodding me along with questions: I learned from this. Further, I am studying 'Selenium' at https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html to make sure I really understand how this works. Thanks for taking the time.